# Snippet creation keystroke/shortcut in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, code-snippets

So I was using Eclipse and I went to go copy some import statements I had selected. I somehow mis-typed, and the coolest thing happened: a `snippet` package was created, and a `Snippet.java` class was created that looked like this:

```
package snippet;

public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Selected code
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what the keyboard shortcut for doing this is? It seems like a immensely useful feature to have. I have tried searching online, but had no luck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what happens when you copy code and paste it into the Package Explorer.
If you have a project selected, it will create the snippet package, if you have nothing selected then it will create a new java project named `_pasted_code_`

Comment: Thanks. Because I am using working sets the project was not visible, just the error => was driving me crazy!