# What is _pasted_code_ when I try to paste something

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was working on a program one day and when I tried to copy and past something using the keyboard shortcut, it created a new project _pasted_code_ with the package snippet. I'm not quite sure what I did to set it up like this. Is there a way to fix this so I can normally copy and paste again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919274/snippet-creation-keystroke-shortcut-in-eclipse

Make sure to google problems you might have before asking on StackOverflow.

Comment: I saw that when I originally looked it up. I'm not in the package explorer when I paste it. I set my cursor to my .java file yet it still does it

Comment: @user2281389 Have you tried restarting Eclipse? Otherwise you may want to file a bug report (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/)